# Регулярное выражение для .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод и Co.
Прошу помощи в создании правил для .htaccess:
ссылка **http://url.com** открывает индексный файл(как и положено на приличном сайте)
ссылка вида **http://url.com/page/post1** отработается как **http://url.com/page.php?id=post1**
ссылка вида **http://url.com/post/post1** отработается как **http://url.com/post.php?id=post1**
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*?)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

примерно так, за работоспособность не отвечаю.

Comment: редирект работает, но на условной странице **page.php** перестали отображаться графика. Пути к графике прописаны относительно, **<img src='pic/image.jpg' />**

Comment: почему всегда забывают проверять наличие файлов? 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`